# deleted coupon code keeps showing up as exisiting

Tags: cart, shopping, rules

im trying to add a new rule and create a coupon code named "Discount", and have used the same name in the past. the problem is: I've deleted that particular coupon a while back, but magento keeps telling me that the coupon code exists! 
I don't see it anywhere in the list of rules which are currently active. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, try reindexing your site and flushing your cache.

If that doesn't work then take a look at your `salesrule_coupon` table to ensure that it's not stuck in there.

Since your coupon code is called "Discount", try:

`select * from salesrule_coupon where code like "%iscount%";`

If it shows up then delete the row and try to create the coupon again.